# MySQL Tagging Rows in Sequence based on a pattern

Tags: mysql, design-patterns, sequence

I have a column which I am trying to convert in MySQL into another column with a pattern where ever there are consecutive 1s in the data. Please see the example dataset below

Dataset Sample: https://1drv.ms/x/s!ApGNZAoiMmX3gi9OR7SUxt3ou84v?e=tuSV7f

[image: example data with input and desired output]

Following is the code I have written but not able to make it work and any suggestions would be helpful.

```
select rownum,result,movingsum,new_result
(select rownum,result,movingsum,
    if(result_norm_max=0,0,if(movingsum=1,1,0)) as new_result
from 
    (select rownum,result,
    sum(result) over (order by rownum rows between 2 preceding and current row) as movingsum
    from mytable) a;
```

The issue is, the above code doesn't return the output needed for all required logic of:

- when result column is 0 new_result should be 0
- when result is 1, new_result = 1 but only when previous 2 new_results are 0

Any suggestion on how I should approach this will be useful.
Thanks!

Comment: While remembering that rows in RDBMS tables represent *unordered* sets, please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I have added sample dataset

Comment: That's true only if  the question is about Excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some tries I was able to find the solution which is close to what I need as mentioned below. I used 2 variables to carry out the trick,

```
select rownum,result,
    if (result= 0, 0, if(@n = 1, if(@m >= 7, 1 , 0), 1)) as new_max,
    if (result= 0, 0, if(@n = 1, 
        case when @m >= 7 then @m:=0 else 0 end
            , 1)) as new_max1,
    if (result= 0, if(@m>0,@m:=@m-1,@m:=0), if(@n = 1, @m:=@m+1,@m:=@m-1)) as new_m,
    @n := result
    from mytable a, (select @n:= 0, @m:= 0) b
```